# Usage of Lazy<T> vs. Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

As on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx):

> "Use an instance of `Lazy<T>` to defer the creation of a large or
> **resource-intensive**   object or the execution of a resource-intensive task, particularly when such creation or execution
> might not occur during the lifetime of the program."

For a factory-pattern I could use a `Lazy<T>` to create instances instead of using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

by returning a

```
new Lazy<T>().value
```

something like:

```
return Lazy<IFactoryInstance>(() => new Car()).Value;
```

that gives me the ability to initialize the object-instance in a different ways per type/instance etc. from a method.

But I have my doubts when reading the text from MSDN. What is a good practice for a similar piece of code? And why not use `Lazy<T>`?

Comment: A `Lazy<T>` lazily initializes only one value/instance. How would you use it with the factory pattern?

Comment: dtb is correct.  Once the `Lazy<T>` has instantiated a class, it's done.  It's not a factory.

Comment: Are you trying to create a factory that returns Lazy<T>'s? That's obviously doable, and possibly useful (if you think consumers will use the factory without necessarily requiring the object.) Using Lazy<T> *as* the factory is not (as dtb pointed out.)

Comment: @ dtb  correct, but I could return a new Lazy<T>().Value.

Comment: `Lazy<T>` defers execution of the lambda until there is demand for the value. Demand for the value is indicated by accessing the Value property. So `return Lazy<IFactoryInstance>(() => new Car()).Value;` is just an inefficient way to say `return new Car();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Lazy<T>` type and `Activator.CreateInstance` function have very different purposes.

- `Lazy<T>`: Used to create delay initialized values once and only once. I disagree with MSDN's definition of resource intensive and simply replace it with "Used to create expensive types on demand vs. on initialization".
- `Activator.CreateInstance`: Used to create type instances based on runtime information

The `Lazy<T>` type in itself is not suitable for a factory pattern because it's useful for creating a single instance (not many).

Comment: ...though as the comments to the OP point out, there may be some value in setting up the factory (or an IoC) to return `Lazy<T>`s, allowing for lazy instantiation of "optional" dependencies.

Comment: @JaredPar, nice answer, but... what can I use in a similar way? is there something similar like Lazy<T>(Func<T>) that acceps similar parameters?

Comment: @KeithS I can see how it would be useful as part of a factory pattern implementation. But the question to me read more as using `Lazy<T>` as the basis of a factory pattern.

Comment: @Caspar what part of `Lazy<T>` are you finding advantageous?

Comment: Updated the answer, but perhaps I am making things too complex here ;)

Comment: @JaredPar, thanks, for this answer and helping to keep  my learning curve upwards.